# why is the sectsty package not working (for me) with \paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, sectsty

I want to retouch the behavior of `\paragraph` but something is bad in my code, Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{{\color{black!80} \thechapter-\arabic{section}}}
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
  \makeatother
\chapterfont{\thispagestyle{empty}\huge \sffamily \color{blue!50!black}\raggedleft}
\sectionfont{\sffamily}
\subsectionfont{\fcolorbox{blue!80}{blue!80}{\phantom{XXX}} \color{blue}\sffamily}
\subsubsectionfont{\fcolorbox{green!80}{green!80}{\phantom{XX}}\phantom{X} \color{green!50!black}\sffamily}
\paragraphfont{\fcolorbox{red!50!black}{red!50!black}{\phantom{XXX}}\phantom{XXX} \color{white}\sffamily}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{este capítulo}
    cap
    \section{en la sección}
    escribiendo
    \subsection{subsección}
    mas todavia
    \subsubsection{subsub}
    y finalmente    
    \paragraph{que un párrafo}
    no funciona
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\paragraph}` is clashing with `\paragraphfont`. Moreover, why use `\color{white}` in `\paragraphfont`? That hides the paragraph title when the redefinition of `\paragraph` is commented out.

Comment: The redefinition of `\paragraph` should occur *before* you load `sectsty`.

Comment: Yes, @Masroor, my mistake. originally my code was "viol" and previously defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with the `sectsty` package, it's generally a good idea to undertake any redefinitions of `\section`, `\subsection`, etc *before* loading `sectsty` and issuing instructions such as `\chapterfont`, `\sectionfont`, etc.

A separate issue: In your definition of `\paragraphfont`, the directive `\color{white}` serves to make the string "que un párrafo" (the argument of `\paragraph`) invisible. Change the directive to `\color{orange}`, say, to verify this claim.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % uncomment this, if desired

\renewcommand{\thesection}{%\color{black!80} 
    \thechapter-\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}%
    {4}{\z@}{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\thispagestyle{empty}\huge \sffamily \color{blue!50!black}\raggedleft}
\sectionfont{\sffamily}
\subsectionfont{\fcolorbox{blue!80}{blue!80}{\phantom{XXX}} \color{blue}\sffamily}
\subsubsectionfont{\fcolorbox{green!80}{green!80}{\phantom{XX}}\phantom{X} \color{green!50!black}\sffamily}
\paragraphfont{\fcolorbox{red!50!black}{red!50!black}{\phantom{XXX}}\phantom{XXX} \color{orange}\sffamily}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{este capítulo}
    cap
    \section{en la sección}
    escribiendo
    \subsection{subsección}
    mas todavia
    \subsubsection{subsub}
    y finalmente    
    \paragraph{que un párrafo}
    ahora funciona bien
\end{document}
```